# Is it sufficient to say that no odd divides an even number to prove it is a power of two?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A short preface:

> I'm reading the book Godel Esher Bach: Eternal Golden Braid, it
>   describes a system which it calls Typographic Number Theory. There is
>   a question in the book that asks to represent a statement "b is a
>   power of two" in terms of TNT. You will probably recognize the
>   operations of TNT at once, so I'll not spend much time describing it,
>   only what's relevant.

Here's the formula I came up with (and the interpretation, in case I've got the formula wrong):

$$
\forall{a}\forall{b}\exists{c}\forall{d}\exists{e}:<<(b=Scc)\land\lnot(b*d=a)>\land(a=e*SS0)>
$$

The $<$ and $>$ symbols are used to delimit the logic expressions. $S$ stands for `successor of`, so $S0$ is 1, $SS0$ is 2 and so on. $Sx$ is a successor of $x$ whatever $x$ is.

In plain language, the formula above is meant to say: "whatever $b$ is, given it is a sum of any two $c$ and one (that is if $b$ is odd) it is not the case that it multiplied with any number $d$ can produce $a$ (does not divide $a$). Yet there have to be such number $e$ which if multiplied by two will produce $a$ ($a$ is even).

I'm not pretending to have any academic background, so please excuse me if the formulation is poor!

Comment: Since every integer $>1$ has a unique factorization into primes, and every prime $>2$ is odd, it follows that any number $>1$ with no odd divisors $>1$ has only $2$ in its prime factorization, thus is a power of two.

Comment: Right on, Jaycob Coleman!

Comment: That is a good answer @JaycobColeman

Comment: @JaycobColeman yay! Thanks a lot! You probably could post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Why are you using $<$ and $>$ as parentheses?

Comment: @GitGud that is the original syntax of the book (at least the edition that I have).

Comment: @wvxvw Beware of such devious choices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since every integer $>1$ has a unique factorization into primes, and every prime $>2$ is odd, it follows that any number $>1$ with no odd divisors $>1$ has only $2$ in its prime factorization, thus is a power of two.

Someone else could probably give something in more formal language and whatnot, but whatever floats your boat!

Answer (score 3):

You do not state "$b$ is a power of two". In fact your statement does not have a free variable at all.
Also $Scc$ is not even well-formed.
On the other hand, your idea to rewrite "$b$ is a power of two" as "all divisors $>1$ of $b$ are even" is fine.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'd have to work on that. Sure $Scc$ was meant to be $S(c+c)$.